# Experience Profile search results show fewer visits than in details

Tags: xdb, experience-profile

For at least one of my contacts, when I search for them it shows that they have only one visit on the results page, but if I click into the details and look at the Activity tab and the visits there, I'm seeing 2 visits.

What might cause this discrepancy and how do I fix it?

I am worried that this may be happening with many more, if not all of my contacts and cannot trust the results I am seeing.

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore support finally responded that this is being caused by the shared session timing out before the private session for the problem contacts. The following were the suggested solutions:

1. Upgrade to Sitecore 9.x. In this version the visit counter no longer depends on sessions - and this is the most reliable solution I can see at this moment.
2. Try to increase shared session timeout. This will help ensuring that the shared session expires after the private one, and also this is the quickest possible workaround.
3. Find a way to fix the existing problematic contacts and perform this operation on a scheduled basis.This way the new contacts will be affected by the problem until the process for fixing such contacts is started. This process will require direct modifications of the mongoDB, which is a bit risky.

None have been confirmed as a resolution yet. We have had other concerns and no time to work on it.

Answer (score 1):

Search results are served from Analytics index while actual details are loaded directly from the storage. It might be that the contact was indexed correctly or one of his interactions was not indexed at all. It should not happen during normal operations, but you could check indexing logs for any anomalies. To fix the search results view you would need to rebuild Analytics index (`/sitecore/admin/RebuildReportingDB.aspx`).

Comment: The process status has been at "Starting" for hours, is that normal?

Comment: No, that's not normal. The status should change from "Starting" to "Started" within a couple of minutes. Do you see any errors in Sitecore logs?

Comment: Do you have reporting.secondary database configured? It's used by rebuild process.

Comment: I think it could not connect to the secondary server. I switched to a different server and it quickly passed on to "WaitReadyToReceiveData". We have a very small site with very little traffic (maybe 1k-2k/month). Should I expect this to be a swift process?

Comment: The rebuild finished, but it did not change anything. Search results say one visit and Activity > Visits says 2.

Comment: @Michael, sorry for not getting back to you. Have you found cause of the issue? Are you running Sitecore 8?

Comment: We have not found the cause yet. We are running 8.2 Update 3. Sitecore support is also working on it and requested a dump from MongoDB, but they have yet to respond with additional information after 1 week.